# Get ID of newly created product attribute option

Tags: attributes, option

In my magento store I am creating a new product attribute option as so:

```
$new_name = 'my-new-option';

$_attribute =  Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product', 'my-attribute');
$_options = $_attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true);
foreach ($_options as $opt) {
    if($opt['label'] === $new_name)
    {
        $exists = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!$exists)
{
    $option['attribute_id'] = 141;
    $option['value'][0][0] = $new_name;
    $setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
    $setup->addAttributeOption($option);
}
```

This works but after adding the option i need to return the value/id to use further down my script. How can I do so?

Answer (score 2):

```
$_attribute =  Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product', 'my-attribute');
```

**Get Eav option collectrion:**

```
$optionCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
                ->setAttributeFilter($_attribute->getId());
```

BY Default any most of collection is filter by primary ket asc order

**So you can get newly created  option of this attribute**

```
$newInsertedOption=$optionCollection>getLastItem();
var_dump($newInsertedOption->getData());
```

Comment: Thank you Amit. Can i ask though - this script gets called when a customers updates their account profile information (my-new-option comes from what they enter). If say customer A and customer B clicked and ran this at the same time - could `getLastItem` be mixed up between customers? If that makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

just call the new product again and get the attribute from it.

Comment: I haven't assigned the attribute to any product yet at this stage